# Maven resolves only the first dependencyManagement import

Tags: java, maven-3, dependency-management, dependency-resolution

I have the following within a project using Maven 3.2.2 on CentOS:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>common.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>dm-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${bomVersion}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

With the order given in the example, my `dm-bom` will be found correctly, but not the `vaadin-bom`. If I define the `vaadin-bom` first, then the problem is the other way around.

Does Maven have a problem with repository definition when a project defines more than one imported `dependencyManagement` pom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was Maven 3.2.2 and having mulitple import of dependencyManagement into a pom.xml. After having upgraded to Maven 3.8.1, I don't see the issue anymore.